# Powershell script to loop through NSGs, remove and then add rule

Tags: powershell

i have the following script attached which should loop through the NSGs in my subscription and then remove the rulse for allowing RDP and then re-add the rule with a new Prioity, but it isnt quite working.

The script removes the rule but doesnt re-add the rule.

```
nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
    $nsgRules = Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg 
    foreach ($nsgRule in $nsgRules) { 
        if ($nsgRule.name -like "*Allow-RDP") {
            $nsgRule.Name
            Remove-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $nsgRule.Name -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg 
        } 
    } 
    $nsg | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup

Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name Allow-RDP -Description "Allow RDP" -Access `
    Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 200 -SourceAddressPrefix Internet `
    -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389 |
    Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup 
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not tested. Please try it before using it in production.
Try by adding:

```
nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
    # Your code is removed for more visibility
    $nsg | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name Allow-RDP -Description "Allow RDP" -Access `
    Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 200 -SourceAddressPrefix Internet `
    -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389 |
    $nsg | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup 
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/scripts/service-fabric-powershell-add-nsg-rule